# Mysql Recursive Stored Procedure...Limit 0 reached...can't change the max_sp_recursion_depth variable

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures

UPDATE: Ok, I was able to debug this and found that the by doing this `select @@max_sp_recursion_depth` I can see that the variable is set at 15, however, when I run the call back to itself with `CALL single_limb_portfolio_list(xaccount_id, xparent_portfolio_id);` I get the error stating the Recursive Limit 0 was reached, but it never iterated over itself once'

---

When I run the recursive stored procedure below I keep getting the "Recursive Limit 0 was exceeded" even though I set it to be `SET max_sp_recursion_depth = 15 ;`

Am I setting this variable in the wrong place?  It's acting like it never gets set and always stays at zero?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Recursive Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`aaron`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `single_limb_portfolio_list`(xaccount_id INT, IN portf_id_in INT, OUT str_portf_list VARCHAR(455))
BEGIN
    DECLARE xportfolio_ID INT DEFAULT NULL ;
    DECLARE xp_name INT DEFAULT NULL ;
    DECLARE xparent_portfolio_id INT DEFAULT NULL ;
    DECLARE xstr_list VARCHAR(455) ;

  SET max_sp_recursion_depth = 15 ;

    SELECT portfolio_id, p_name, parent_portfolio_id
    FROM portfolio
    WHERE account_id = xaccount_id
    AND archived = 0
    AND portfolio_id = portf_id_in
    INTO xportfolio_ID, xp_name, xparent_portfolio_id;

   IF xportfolio_ID IS NULL /* We have reached the top of the tree and there are no more parents for the portfolio list */
    THEN
    SET str_portf_list = xstr_list; #Set the full tree list to the variable that will be inserted as a row into the temp table previously created
   ELSE
    CALL single_limb_portfolio_list(xaccount_id, xparent_portfolio_id); #call the sproc with the next portfolio id to get the next parent id
    SET xstr_list = concat(xp_name,"->",xstr_list);   #Add the portfolio name to the overall portfolio list. Output like: "California -> Los Angelas"
   END IF;

END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a non recursive solution which you can adapt for your model (http://pastie.org/1259300)

```
drop table if exists product;

create table product
(
prod_id smallint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
name varchar(255) not null,
parent_id smallint unsigned null,
key (parent_id)
)engine = innodb;


insert into product (name, parent_id) values
('Products',null), 
   ('Systems & Bundles',1), 
   ('Components',1), 
      ('Processors',3), 
      ('Motherboards',3), 
        ('AMD',5), 
        ('Intel',5), 
           ('Intel LGA1366',7);


delimiter ;

drop procedure if exists product_hier;

delimiter #

create procedure product_hier
(
in p_prod_id smallint unsigned
)
begin

declare v_done tinyint unsigned default 0;
declare v_depth smallint unsigned default 0;

create temporary table hier(
 parent_id smallint unsigned, 
 prod_id smallint unsigned, 
 depth smallint unsigned default 0
)engine = memory;

insert into hier select parent_id, prod_id, v_depth from product where prod_id = p_prod_id;

/* http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html */

create temporary table tmp engine=memory select * from hier;

while not v_done do

    if exists( select 1 from product p inner join hier on p.parent_id = hier.prod_id and hier.depth = v_depth) then

        insert into hier 
            select p.parent_id, p.prod_id,  v_depth + 1 from product p 
            inner join tmp on p.parent_id = tmp.prod_id and tmp.depth = v_depth;

        set v_depth = v_depth + 1;          

        truncate table tmp;
        insert into tmp select * from hier where depth = v_depth;

    else
        set v_done = 1;
    end if;

end while;

select 
 p.prod_id,
 p.name as prod_name,
 b.prod_id as parent_prod_id,
 b.name as parent_prod_name,
 hier.depth
from 
 hier
inner join product p on hier.prod_id = p.prod_id
inner join product b on hier.parent_id = b.prod_id
order by
 hier.depth, hier.prod_id;

drop temporary table if exists hier;
drop temporary table if exists tmp;

end #

delimiter ;


call product_hier(3);

call product_hier(5);
```

Comment: I'll give you the nod...thanks for the reply.  I did something like this, but not in a stored procedure.  I already had a php function that I wrote to traverse the tree and give me what I wanted, and I realized I could simply run that function then insert into a table the tree structure I wanted.