# 'max_sp_recursion_depth' variable doesn't appear to set causing "Recursive limit 0 was exceeded" error

Tags: sql, recursion, xampp, mariadb

Quick note, I know this question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056421/mysql-recursive-stored-procedure-limit-0-reached-cant-change-the-max-sp-rec), but the 'answer' gives an alternative which doesn't involve recursion. I want to get recursion working. Here's some code I wrote to demonstrate the problem:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `test` (x INT)
BEGIN

  SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'max_sp_recursion_depth';

  IF x = 0 THEN
    SELECT 1;
  ELSE
    CALL `test`(x-1);
  END IF;

END
```

Returns:

```
+------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name          | Value |
+------------------------+-------+
| max_sp_recursion_depth | 64    |
+------------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)

ERROR 1456 (HY000) at line 43 in file: 'workspace.sql': Recursive limit 0 (as set by the max_sp_recursion_depth variable) was exceeded for routine test
```

**What I've tried**

I will update this as I try more things:

- setting the variable via the MariaDB CLI
- setting the variable via PHPMyAdmin
- restarting MariaDB
- restarted the entire server
- restarted my computer (currently running in a development environment on my mac) and the variable has reset to 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET GLOBAL ...
```

does not have any effect on the current connection; only future connections.  (Exception:  Some variables are "only global"; those probably do show up immediately.)

```
SET SESSION ...
```

Is what to do to make it work for the current connection.

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
max_sp_recursion_depth=255
```

To the [my.cnf](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/configuring-mariadb-with-option-files/) file and that fixed the issue. Still unclear as to why the variable wasn't set via the command line, but  it works. Although I am still interested so if anyone sees this and wants to elaborate, you're an amazing human!